# Scaffolding user ID resetting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

in the application i am currently creating in ruby on rails. I am trying to do some tests in rails console where i have to destroy data in the database and the database is connected to a server. I am importing an XML and parsing it and putting it into a database with scaffolding.

Now what i need: Basically what i am attempting to do is to destroy the data and replace it with a new one every week..but the problem i am getting, the userid is gone up to 700+ and there are only 50 records :S cause it doesnt reset...

To delete all records i am currently using "whatever.destroy_all" does the trick

Any help?

Btw i am using SQLITE

Comment: What's the problem with big ids?

Comment: cause i want to interlink between another scaffold, would that cause a problem??

Answer (score 0):

The `ID` column created in the table usually is set as **unique** and to **increment by 1** for each new record, which is why each time you destroy and add new data the `ID` keeps getting higher.

The fact that the ID # is getting larger and larger is **not an issue** at all.

If you really want to start back at zero, I would think you could drop the table and recreate it, but that seems like overkill for a trivial issue.

Regarding the connection to the other scaffold, how are you connecting the two and what do they both represent?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the data population for testing should be done through fixtures (or easy tools such as factorygirl etc..)

The main advantage of having a fix data set is you can run your tests in any environment. But as per your requirement you can do something like this,

When you populate the date through the active records pass the id parameter as well

```
Ex: User.new(:id => 1, :name => "sameera").create
```

By this way you can have constant id's But make sure you increment the id accordingly.